# why the data is not entering in database after connecting the SQL connector?

Tags: database

in this project the connector is alright and the code is ok but the data is not entering in the database.
I have tried many things but its not working. is there any solution available for this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJGi6.png)